# Regular Expression - followed by

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a regex that match this

```
123/456

123/456/?
```

but not this

```
123/456/
```

I want on the second / it must be followed by a ?.

For Example I would like it to match this

```
'123/456'.match(X) // return ['123/456']
'123/456/?'.match(X) // return ['123/456/?']
'123/456/'.match(X) // return null
```

**Update**

I missed to say one important thing. It must not end with '?', a string like '123/456/?hi' should also match

Comment: Could the numbers be different than 123 and 456? If yes, how long can they be?

Comment: @sp00m, yes, it can be any digits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this regex: `\d{3}/\d{3}(/\?.*)?`

It will match

- 3 digits
- followed by a `/`
- followed by 3 digits
- followed by `/?any_text` (e.g. `/?hi`) (optional)

[This example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5Cd%7B3%7D/%5Cd%7B3%7D%28/%5C?.%2a%29?%24&input=123/456%0A123/456/?%0Abut%20not%20this%0A123/456/%0A123/456/?hi) uses regular expression anchors like `^` and `$`, but they are not required if you only try to match against the target string.

```
var result = '123/456/?hi'.match(/\d{3}\/\d{3}(\/\?.*)?/);
if (result) {
    document.write(result[0]);
}
else {
    document.write('no match');
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could replace your `{3}` by `+` and your `.*` by `[^ ]*`

Comment: @sp00m The OP still doesn't say if there can by any number of digits.

Comment: I get error when I try `'123/456/?hi'.match(/\d{3}/\d{3}(/\?.*)?/)`

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression will work `/^\d{3}\/\d{3}(\/\?.*)?/`

See this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTVPy/2/).

Note: if you think it should match  any number of digits then use `\d+` instead of `\d{3}`. The later matches exactly 3 digits.

Comment: I missed to say one important thing. It must not end with '?', a string like '123/456/?hi' should also match.

Comment: aha. Then update your question. I have update the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
[0-9]+/[0-9]+(/\?[^ ]*)?
```

Answer (score 0):

What other rules do you have?

If you want to accept all strings with last character other than `?`, use `"[^?]$"`

If you want to accept strings that start with `123/456` and optionally end with `/?`, use `"^123/456(/\?)?$"`

Comment: I missed to say one important thing. It must not end with '?', a string like '123/456/?hi' should match also.

Comment: Then use the first expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
'123/456'.match(/^123\/456(\/\?)?$/) // returns ["123/456", undefined]
'123/456/'.match(/^123\/456(\/\?)?$/) // returns null
'123/456/?'.match(/^123\/456(\/\?)?$/) // returns ["123/456/?", "/?"]
```

EDIT: added the other cases